# How do I use "zealous diff3" with git? And what are the pros and cons?

Tags: git, diff, git-config, diff3

I just read the [release notes for Git 2.35.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.35.0.txt) (note 2.35.1 is already available though).

In those release notes, I saw that:

> - "Zealous diff3" style of merge conflict presentation has been added.

My questions:

1. How do I make git diff / difftool default to "zealous " diff presentation?
2. What are the pros and cons of using it over the default diff presentation mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new "zealous diff3" style is:

```
merge.conflictStyle = zdiff3
```

which you'd set with:

```
git config --global merge.conflictStyle zdiff3
```

for instance (assuming you want this in your per-user configuration).

The default style is `merge`:

```
Here are lines that are either unchanged from the common
ancestor, or cleanly resolved because only one side changed,
or cleanly resolved because both sides changed the same way.
<<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
=======
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt
And here is another line that is cleanly resolved or unmodified.
```

(this example is straight from [the `git merge` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)).  The `diff3` style adds the merge base version in the middle, with vertical bars:

```
Here are lines that are either unchanged from the common
ancestor, or cleanly resolved because only one side changed,
<<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
or cleanly resolved because both sides changed the same way.
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
||||||| base:sample.txt
or cleanly resolved because both sides changed identically.
Conflict resolution is hard.
=======
or cleanly resolved because both sides changed the same way.
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt
And here is another line that is cleanly resolved or unmodified.
```

Note that in order to show the difference between the *base* version and *both branch-tip versions*, the line:

```
or cleanly resolved because both sides changed the same way.
```

which used to be *outside* the `<<<<<<< ... >>>>>>>` section (because it was cleanly resolved) is now *inside* this section.

What `zdiff3` does is take the same "or cleanly resolved" path that `merge` takes:

```
Here are lines that are either unchanged from the common
ancestor, or cleanly resolved because only one side changed,
or cleanly resolved because both sides changed the same way.
<<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
||||||| base:sample.txt
or cleanly resolved because both sides changed identically.
Conflict resolution is hard.
=======
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt
And here is another line that is cleanly resolved or unmodified.
```

This is a lie, of sorts, but it's a *useful* lie.

Note that if you'd like, you can take any existing conflicted file and re-create the conflict in a new merge style:

```
git checkout --conflict=zdiff3 conflicted.txt
```

(or the same with `git restore` but I haven't retrained my fingers yet ).  **Be careful with this** as it overwrites any attempt you've made at merging.